# list with multiple select2 very slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

I've got a list with 100 records. For each record I've got 2 selectboxes which I convert to a select2 selectbox. Problem is that building the list takes 10 seconds. When I'm not using select2 it takes 1 second.

Any idea how I can make it faster?

Comment: Maybe you want to show us some code and benchmarks. Also tell us how fast you need it to get.

Comment: @Leon van der Veen Any feedback would be appreciated

Comment: 10 seconds? 100 records? Did you miss a few zeros somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Apply a graphical plugin to 200 elements take time.

You could try to hide the container containing the select boxes before applying the Select2 plugins and display it only after page loading (use JQuery event to be notified). Therefore, it will avoid browser refreshing.

You should also consider to not display all your select boxes on the same page (use pagination?).

Or apply the plugin only to the visible select boxes on the screen. Spy the scroll event to apply the plugin to the new elements displayed.